# manufacturer products and address mapping in nopcommerce

Tags: database, nopcommerce

we sell virtual gift and social experience like hot air balloon rides, tree house, horse riding, Ferrari car riding etc. These experience provides by different suppliers at different address. We are using nopcommerce as our development platform and as we thought our social experiences are products and supplier are manufactures but we still having problem in mapping addresses. The supplier has two kind of address. One the office address of the supplier and second address is where experience will take place. In other words, the products we sell will have many address and also has relationship with manufactures.

The relationship more or less will be

manufactures have many products and one product can be supplied by many manufactures.

manufactures has many address and they also provide experiences(products) at different addresses.

we need product information, supplier information and then address information for each experience(products). The entity relationship is

[image]

Is this diagram ok? Or what will be the way to map this information in nopcommerce?

Answer (score 0):

You can use specification attributes in nopCommerce for the providing different addresses of the product.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.If I will use specification attributes then how can I link these addresses with manufactures or supplier?